# How can I determine the bitrate type of mp3 files with Python?

Tags: python, mp3, bitrate

How to determine the type of the bitrate used for an mp3 file, e.g. CBR, VBR or ABR?

Answer (score 20):

[mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen) works for me. Here is an excerpt from one of my scripts.

```py
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

f = MP3(musicfile)
bitrate = f.info.bitrate / 1000
```

Comment: You can use `f = mutagen.File(musicfile)` to not be tied to MP3.